# Creating a Custom Column from CurrentDate

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

I'm trying to create a new custom column from a conditional statement and current date.

Next picture explains exactly what i need to get with power query.

[image: THIS IMAGE EXPLAIN WHAT I WANT TO DO]

An example of what I need from pseudocode is:

```
if [fecha fin de plazo]>=CurrentDate and [fecha CIERRE investigación]=null
then "string"
```

My biggest problem is I don't know how to extract the current date with PowerQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the DateTime.LocalNow you get the date and time of your system, the problem is at time to compareting the date value with the result of DateTime.LocalNow() becsause you need to compare only dates.

That's why It must use DateTime.Date. This fucntion returns the date component of DateTime.LocalNow().

```
if [date1] >= DateTime.Date(DateTime.LocalNow()) and [date2]=null
then "string"
```

You can get more information about this functions here:

---

[DateTime.LocalNow()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/datetime-localnow)
[DateTime.Date()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/datetime-date)

Comment: Please consider adding at least some explanation as though why this answer the question

Comment: Please add some description to your code explaining what is going on and why. This is good practice. If you don't, your answer is in risk of being deleted. It has already been flagged as low quality.

Answer (score 1):

You could try using,

```
if [fecha fin de plazo]>= DateTime.LocalNow() and [fecha CIERRE investigación]=null
then "string"
```

[DateTime.LocalNow()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/datetime-localnow)

Comment: almost! your code returns me an error but I was from your request I found out what I needed. To make it work properly I added DateTime.Date() to DateTime.LocalNow(). The result was DateTime.Date(DateTime.LocalNow()) because your code returns me date and time and I'm comparing the columns just by date

Comment: @NoeliaSanchoMendez glad you found a way. Though I don't have any way to test given code :)